# Einstein Summation Notation and Kronecker Delta Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, kronecker-delta

> Evaluate $\delta_j^iv_iu^j, \delta^2_j\delta^j_kv^k,$ and $\delta^3_j\delta^j_1$.

The Kronecker-delta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta

Einstein notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

The solution says to simplify the expressions by using the $\delta$-function index replacement property:

$\delta^i_jv_iu^j = v_ju^j = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{u}$.

I don't understand what the "$\delta$-function index replacement property" is?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\delta^i_j$ is 0 if $i\ne j$ and it is 1 if $i = i$. So if you "contract" it with an indexed quantity $v_k$, i.e. evaluate the sum $\sum_{i=1}^N \delta^i_j v_i$, all of the terms disappear except the one where $i=j$ and the result is $v_j$. The summation convention simplifies the notation by implicitly summing over repeated indices, so the equality

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \delta^i_j v_i = v_j$$

can be written as

$$ \delta^i_j v_i = v_j$$

where the summation over $i$ is implied. In effect, multiplying $v_i$ by $\delta^i_j$ and summing over $i$, *replaces* the index $i$ in $v_i$ by the index $j$.

In the expression

$$\delta^i_j v_i u^j$$

both indices are repeated, that is there are *two* implied summations, one over $i$ and one over $j$. What the abbreviation really means is

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \delta^i_j v_i u^j $$

You can do the sums in either order, so let's use the first part of the answer to do the summation over $i$:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \delta^i_j v_i u^j = \sum_{j=1}^N v_j u^j $$

But using the summation convention, the RHS can be abbreviated as $v_j u^j$, the sum of the products of the corresponding components of the two vectors, i.e. the dot product.

The summation convention is convenient, but like any abbreviation, it hides things under the rug so to speak. So if you find yourself confused, just expand it: write out the explicit sums - for small $N$ (say $N=3$), you can even expand the sums and write each term out explicitly. That should clarify things completely.

Comment: I think I understand now. And $u^j$ would obviously just remain the same since it already has $j$ as its index?

Comment: I added a new section to the answer. I hope it clarifies things wrt $j$, but feel free to ask more questions.